# arduino pyfirmata analog reading

Tags: python, arduino

Im having trouble reading the analog value of my Arduino using pyfirmata. Every time I ask to read the value of `('a:0:i)` it will always return a random set of numbers, regardless of whether I have an analog pin plugged in or not.

```
import pyfirmata

board = pyfirmata.Arduino('COM4')

it = pyfirmata.util.Iterator(board)
it.start()

analog_read = board.get_pin('a:0:i')

while True:
    print(analog_read.read())
    time.sleep(2)
```

The output will return

```
0.3255
0.3255
0.3294
#and up
```

Comment: Does it read correctly with a load?  If you don't have a load, the pin floats, and the readings can be random.

Comment: This can be with or without a load

Comment: How random?  What you're showing there is +/- 1%, which is pretty darned good.